# gfortran not finding pre-compiled module despite -I flag

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to create a folder that contains all the modules I may use. Rather than compiling those modules whenever I need them, I pre-compiled the modules within that folder and would like to use the `-I` compiler flag to point to the pre-compiled modules (referenced in the [`gfortran` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gfortran)). Despite that, I get a compiler (linker?) error that the module cannot be found. For example, consider this directory structure:

```
project_folder/
├─ src/
│  ├─ main.f90
├─ modules/
│  ├─ my_mod.f90
```

`main.f90`:

```
program main
    use my_mod, only : f
    implicit none

    print *, f(20)

end program main
```

`my_mod.f90`:

```
module my_mod
    implicit none
    private
    public :: f

contains
    function f(arg) result(retval)
        integer, intent(in) :: arg
        integer :: retval
        
        retval = arg**2
        
    end function f
end module my_mod
```

Within the `modules` directory I compiled `my_mod` using

```
gfortran -c my_mod.f90
```

And within the `src` directory I tried to compile `main` using

```
gfortran -I../modules main.f90
```

When I try the `src` compilation I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc82F9xs.o: in function `MAIN__':
main.f90:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `__my_mod_MOD_f'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I properly tell `gfortran` where the modules are so I can use pre-compiled modules?

Comment: You need to link in the object file.  `gfortran -I../modules main.f90 ../modules/my_mod.o`

Comment: @steve That works, but I thought the point of using `-I` was so that I didn't have to add every object file. I thought it would look in the specified directory for all the files it needed if they weren't in the calling directory. I was hoping to use this to simplify my `Makefiles`--I think I have to spend more time learning how to create `Makefiles` so I don't have to worry about this.

Comment: The `-I` option tells the compiler where it (successfully) found the module file, but the module file isn't what contains the implementation of procedures. The error comes from the _linker_, not the compiler, and there's no connection between the module file and any object the linker requires. Consider that we could rename `my_mod.o` to `somethingelse.o` or include `my_mod.o` in an archive or shared library. This latter being quite common, and we need `-L... -l...` frequently even when using `-I...`.

Comment: @jared In 2024 (or any year say 2010+) it is not worth spending your time learning how to create Makefiles for a language like Fortran. Either learn how to create Makefiles automatically (perhaps using CMake) or learn a buildsystem that does not use Makefiles at all (meson, scons, waf,...). In any case you will need to learn the difference between module files and object files because they are completely separate and some modules do not contain any code that would and up in an object file and one object file can contain code from multiple modules.

Comment: Often, you will have one object file for one source file. But there can be no module in a source file and there can be many modules in one source file.